# Gradle KTS Build Files

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Google released an updated version of **Android Studio 3.5**. After having updated to this version I get this warning below:

```
This project uses Gradle KTS build files which are not fully supported. 
Some functions may be affected.
```

However, I believe this warning is restricted to developers who are using the Gradle’s Kotlin DSL to manage their dependencies. Instead of using groovy scripts.

Comment: Agree.
For those, who don't understand here is an image from Event log https://ibb.co/fdB7KBz

Comment: It seems to be more of a warning. I have not experienced any problems so far.

Comment: I am getting the same warning in A.S. 3.6 Canary 8.  I have a **/buildSrc** folder with Gradle Kotlin files.  Is this supposed to be working?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I have the same implementation in android studio 3.5 but it didn't work for me. Still, it displays waring. Is it work in A.S. 3.6 Canary 8?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also getting the same warning and my app level gradle does not recognize the dependency declared in buildSrc gradle.

Comment: @Srushti Nope,
 still not getting any solutions.

Comment: @George actually it breaks different functionalities on AS, like project structure.

Comment: @desgraci what version of android studio are you running

Comment: @George using currently 3.5.2, but it is also broken with previous versions.

Comment: @desgraci I am using 3.5.2 and the following distribution url: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip in the Gradle wrapper

Comment: I have not  had any issues

Comment: same here, had issues, maybe it is a different detail :/

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now android studio 4.0 is officially Support for Kotlin DSL script files(*.kts) so you need to update it and see the warning removed from your Event Log.

you can check below image and read from it official [Document](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4-0-0-kts)

[image: Remove Warning]